# Erro ao selecionar data focado no bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, datepicker

Estou usando o bootstrap datepicker versão 2.0.

// Comportamento esperado

Ao digitar um dia o mesmo fica focado no calendário então, ao clicar neste dia em foco, deve preencher a data.

// Comportamento real

Ao digitar um dia o mesmo fica focado no calendário então, ao clicar neste da em foco, limpa o campo da data.

Segue exemplo:
https://gyazo.com/ab8857125ef47728c8cc0201c0430d46

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Data</label>
<div class="col-sm-2 disableDiv">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="dteAtual">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-data dtAtual" runat="server" id="dtAtual" name="dtAtual" data-mask="99/99/9999" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: favor colocar os códigos importantes para o desenvolvimento da resposta e entendimento da pergunta acopladas a própria na função de incorporar código, tendo em vista que perguntas e respostas devem por si só conter todo o conteúdo necessário sem depender de funcionamento de sites externos ao stack overflow.